# Where can I find a spinner wheel tutorial?

Tags: android, user-interface

I've been checking out the spinner wheels at http://code.google.com/p/smooth-wheel/ and it's exactly what I'm looking for - spinner wheels like the HTC Sense alarm clock setting.  But I want to learn how to do this and not just implement and use it.

The code to the spinner wheels mentioned above are a bit much when trying to learn so I'm wondering if anyone knows of a step by step tutorial that shows how to create my own spinner wheels that I can build on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a tutorial about it: http://android-devblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/wheel-ui-contol.html (scroll to the end for the "See also" section)

But mostly you should read about drawing on the [`Canvas`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) and implementing a good [`OnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html). With those two concepts you will find that implementing such wheel it's not really difficult.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Aleadam, just what I was looking for, as I (just as Espen above) want to learn how to actually make one, instead of just implementing it.